# How to change the name of UINavigationBar title without affecting prior views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have three views in my app.

My main view controller (called "Technical Data") has a navigation controller embedded. It also has two round rect buttons going to my two other views.

Since the name of my second and third views are pretty long, my navigation bar ends up looking like this: A back button, with the title of "Technical Data" and the "Visual Speci..."

I decided to implement this in my `viewDidLoad` of my second view called "Visual Specialty":

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Back";
```

So with that said, the back button now says "Back" and my navigation title on my second and third view appear complete; "Visual Specialty" and not "Visual Speci..."

The problem is that now when I do go back to the main view, the title on the navigation bar has changed to "Back", so upon initial launch the main view has its name "Technical Data" which is correct, but once I navigate to one of the views and come back, it's now titled "Back"

Do you know of a good workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, use the following code in the `viewDidLoad` method of the first view controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle: @"Back"
                                   style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: I tried adding your code to my viewDidLoad but made no change at all to the back button, it displays "Technical Specialty" still, not even "back", any suggestions as to why this may be?

Comment: maybe try adding it to the initWithNibName:bundle: method instead?

Comment: Sorry should have specified before I tried that as well but no luck :/ @jbums20

Comment: This is the right way to change the title of the back button. However, it needs to be on the first controller (the one having controllers pushed after it)... i.e. your first controller affects the "back" button of the next controller pushed after it. (Set it on the first controller in the `viewDidLoad` method)

Comment: Yes, sorry, JRG-Developer is correct. My mistake; edited to clarify.

Comment: While technically it would still work, it's not great practice to put this in the `initWithNibName:bundle` method, as this is view related (and not related to initializing the controller per se)... Instead, put this in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: This after I placed it in the first view controller worked thanks to both of you, I really appreciate it!!!